# Showing a subset $K$ is a subfield of a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field and let $K$ be a subset of $F$ with at least two elements.
Prove that $K$ is a subfield of $F$ IF, for any $a,b$ ($b\neq  0$) in $K$, $a-b$ and $a\cdot b^{-1}$ belongs to $K$.

> The hint states:
>
> $F^{\ast}=F-{0}$ and $K^{\ast}=K-{0}...$

Here is where I am baffled. Why is the above necessary?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $a,b\in K$ implies $a-b\in K$ and $K$ is not empty, $K$ is a subgroup (additively) of $F$. Similarly, as $a,b\in K\setminus\{0\}$ implies $ab^{-1}$ and $K\setminus\{0\}$ is not empty(!), $K\setminus\{0\}$ is a (multiplicative) subgroup of $F^\times$.

Comment: What is the implication if a,b is in K instead of $a,b \in K $ and 0 not in K?

Comment: Ok, I found a theorem for subfield which was not covered in my notes. I will check back if  further doubts exists

Comment: I do not yet understand why K is non-empty. Is this by assumption?

Comment: Why are we also not interested in the zero element in K? This isn't clear to me..

Comment: $K$ is non-empty because it is given that it contains at least two elements. $K\setminus\{0\}$ is not empty because it then contains still at least on element.  I employed a standrad subgroup criterion twice: If $G$ is a group an $H\subseteq G$, then $H$ is a subgroup iff $H\ne\emptyset$ and$xy^{-1}\in H$ for all  $x,y\in H$.

Comment: But why are we not interested in the zero element in K? It seems we are verifying $K\setminus {0}$ is a subgroup first. But why not verifying K is a subgroup?Does this follows from the definition?

Comment: Sorry but your answer isn't clear. You mention a-b is in K and K is not empty. This isn't the definition for subgroup...what about additive identity and inverses?

Comment: @Mathematicing if it is the case that $K$ is nonempty and $a,b\in K$ implies $a - b\in K$, then suppose $x\in K$. We have $0 = x - x\in K$. Then, for all $b\in K$, $-b = 0-b\in K$. So $K$ contains the additive identity and is closed under inverses.

Comment: @Mathematicing I'm not showing the definition but a well-known much(?) simpler *criterion* for soubgroups (cf. my previous comment)

Comment: To be sure I understood the definition for fields. For a non-empty set to be a field, we need to show it is a commutative ring with unity am I right?

Answer (score 0):

$K$ Inherits conditions of  being field (Associativity of addition and multiplication, Commutativity of addition and multiplication, Distributivity of multiplication over addition, and Existence of additive and multiplicative identity elements)  unless being additive and multiplicative closeness and having additive inverses and multiplicative inverses in it (not out of K).
" $F^{\ast}=F-{0}$ and $K^{\ast}=K-{0}...$" part is to sure this heritage. Since [A field is a ring whose **nonzero elements** form an abelian group under multiplication.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics))